# Nested routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I write a route that maps a path like this?

/powerusers/bob/article-title

This is what I got so far:

```
map.resources :users, :as => "powerusers" do |users|
  users.resources :articles, :as => ''
end
```

This gives me the following route:

/powerusers/:user_id//:id

How do I get rid of the double backslah? /powerusers/admin//first-article?

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, if you don't want the intermediate nested resource (/articles) I wouldn't use the map.resources at all.

Try:

```
map.connect '/powerusers/:user_id/:article_title', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'view_by_title'
```

Comment: Gives me: /powerusers/:user_id/admin/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"articles", :action=>"show"} :/

Answer (score 1):

If I add...

```
  map.resources :users, :as => "powerusers" do |users|
    users.resources :entries, :as => 'article-title'
  end
```

I get the routes below, which include the one you want...

(Substitute "articles" for "entries" for your situation.)

```
                GET    /powerusers(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
                POST   /powerusers(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
                GET    /powerusers/new(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
                GET    /powerusers/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
                GET    /powerusers/:id(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
                PUT    /powerusers/:id(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
                DELETE /powerusers/:id(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy"}
   user_entries GET    /powerusers/:user_id/article-title(.:format)          {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"index"}
                POST   /powerusers/:user_id/article-title(.:format)          {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"create"}
 new_user_entry GET    /powerusers/:user_id/article-title/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"new"}
edit_user_entry GET    /powerusers/:user_id/article-title/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"edit"}
     user_entry GET    /powerusers/:user_id/article-title/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"show"}
                PUT    /powerusers/:user_id/article-title/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"update"}
                DELETE /powerusers/:user_id/article-title/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: This is the url I am looking for: /powerusers/:user_id/:id(.:format) I want to hide the second controller name - article-title in your example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting, would this work?

```
map.resources :users, :as => "powerusers"
map.resources :articles, :path_prefix => '/powerusers/:user_id'
```

I think it won't but a quick test would tell better :)

Comment: Just tried it and the result is /powerusers/:user_id/articles/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"articles", :action=>"show"} I am trying to get rid of article from the url.

Comment: I'm just throwing ideas here (not that i know what im talking about). Have you tried :as => nil instead of :as => '' ?

Comment: was going to suggest you use regular map.connect then instead of users.resources .. but Michal Sofaer already did. Did it work?